# loading posts via ajax and jquery in wordpress

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm using jquery and php to get the previous post from my blog roll.  I'm loading one post at a time on the page and then clicking the previous post link to trigger the ajax call.
The end result is similar to how medium.com pulls the next post article.
the below code works, somewhat, however, it keeps looping and returning a null value when I come to last post.

here's the jquery part

```
loadNextPost : function( callback ) {
      $this = this;
      $.ajax( {
        type: "POST",
       url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        data: {
          action: 'get_prev_post',
          current_url: location.href,
          nonce: MediumJS.nonce,
        }
      } )
      .done( function( post ) {
        if( '' !== post ) {
          $this.nextPost = JSON.parse( post );
        } else {
          $this.nextPost = null;
        }
        callback.call( $this );
      } );
    },
```

now the php function

```
function get_prev_post() {
 global $post;
    $thispost = url_to_postid($_POST['current_url']);

    if ( isset($thispost) ){
    $id = (int) $thispost;
    $post = get_post( $id );
    $attachment_url = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( $previous_post->ID ) );
    $previous_post = get_previous_post();
    //header( "Content-Type: application/json" );
    $array = array('post_id' => $previous_post->ID,'post_content'=> $previous_post->post_content,  'post_title' => $previous_post->post_name,  'permalink' => get_permalink($previous_post->ID), 'attachment_url' => wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id( $previous_post->ID )  ));
    }

    echo json_encode($array);

    //print_r($thispost);
  die();


}
```